# How can you check for foreign key references for a list of records before attempting to delete any of these records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, records, referential-integrity

Is there a way, when you have a list of records, to check if each of these records have foreign key references before you attempt to delete any of these records?

As an example, if I have a list of borrowers and a list of books, you should not be able to delete a borrower from the system if he still has books on loan. (My actual system is much more complicated than that however - a lot more tables.)

I would like to remove the delete option from any borrowers that have books on loan (in that example).

If I try to delete a record with foreign key references, I get an error to the effect of:

> Database access failed: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`tablename`, CONSTRAINT `fkfieldid` FOREIGN KEY (`fieldid`) REFERENCES `tablename` (`fieldid`))

One solution is to write a query to check if each record, in a list of records, has any foreign key references in any of the possible tables it could be referenced.

However, if I wish to display a list of 100 records from a table in my content management system, and I have to run 100 sub-queries in order to display that list, it is obviously very inefficient!

End users become confused when they try to delete a record but they can't because that data is 'in use' elsewhere, so I would rather remove the option to delete to avoid confusion.

Any ideas on what would be the best thing to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using either a sub-query or a join.

ie. sub-query

```
SELECT B.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loans L WHERE L.book_id = b.id) loan_count
FROM books B
```

or join (note that if you allow multiple simultaneous loans, such a book will appear more than once in the results):

```
SELECT B.*, L.book_id AS loaned_out_if_not_null
FROM books B
    LEFT JOIN loans L ON B.id = L.book_id
```

This can of course be shortened down with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT B.id, B.name, COUNT(L.book_id) AS loan_count
FROM books B
    LEFT JOIN loans L ON B.id = L.book_id
GROUP BY B.id, B.name
```

If your database engine has support for CASE, you can avoid the multiple rows in the result by combining that with DISTINCT (of course, DISTINCT also has overhead):

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.*,
    CASE WHEN L.book_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS loaned_out_if_one
FROM books B
    LEFT JOIN loans L ON B.id = L.book_id
```

Of these, I would go with the GROUP BY variant.

Comment: Joins risk duplicating records; EXISTS is a better choice

Comment: This is the type of solution I began looking at, but instead what I have done is to create queries that check each table that has a foreign key for the field in question. I then join those queries using UNION, and do a left outer join with the table containing the primary key. I am hoping that this solution will not be too inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

What you maybe like are transactions.

1) Delete all entries.

2a) If any error occured -> Rollback
2b) If no error occured -> Commit

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html